# QLThumbnailImageCreate does not include images used in HTML files

Tags: macos, cocoa, quicklook

I'm trying to figure an easy way to create screenshots at 1200x800 from nearly one hundred HTML files using QuickLook. This line pretty much sums up with I'm doing:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = QLThumbnailImageCreate(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:layoutHtml isDirectory:NO], CGSizeMake(1280   , 800), (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) @{ (NSString*) kQLThumbnailOptionIconModeKey:@(NO)});
```

Unfortunately the create image does not contain any images used in the HTML file, I only get the question mark "image not found" placeholder. When I use QuickLook from the Finder, images get loaded.

Any ideas on how I could convince QLThumbnailImageCreate to include images?

Thanks,
Ilja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible unless there is hidden [Preview Property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/Reference/QLPreviewRequest_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Preview_Properties).

The [Generating Enriched HTML](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Articles/QLDynamicGeneration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005020-CH15-SW2) also does not mention anything about loading external resources, only `kQLPreviewPropertyAttachmentsKey` which requires the HTML to use the `cid:identifier` URL scheme.

There is [webkit2png](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/) which is a python script that does what you need. Searching for WebKit screenshot solution also brings up some Cocoa code [snippets](http://www.malkinware.com/developer/source/Create-Snapshot-Images-from-Webpages-in-Cocoa.html).

Comment: I ended up building a Cocoa UI app containing a WebView, from which I create the screenshots. Would have preferred my 50-line QuickLook approach in CodeRunner, though.